# How to copy (in clipboard) detailed information of a file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-management, clipboard, windows-server

I'm working with Windows-10.

I have just worked quite a lot to get ShortSha information in the details of a compiled file. Now I would like to copy that information into clipboard but this seems not to work, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, I can select the information, but I can't copy it to clipboard, while I would like to copy the ShortSha in order to find that information back in my Git-Extensions versioning system.

As far as my Windows version is concerned, this is the result of the `winver` command:

[image]

For your information: I'm sure having worked with a Windows version where it was possible copying that information (that was a **Windows Server** version).

**Edit:**
As I'm sure I have done this on another Windows environment, I would like to know the exact name of that feature and an example of such a Windows environment. Like that, I might start searching for a patch.

**Edit2: remark about PowerShell**
In Powershell, I have launched following command, which is very promising:

```
Get-Item "C:\Directory\Application.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

In case I proceed with this solution, I would need to know:

- How to use that result as an input to copy to clipboard (`Set-Clipboard -Value Get-Item "C:\Directory\Application.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion` does not work)
- How to integrate this in Windows context menu (rightclick and launch the command on that file)

**Edit3: remark about Windows Server**
I've found out that I was working on Windows Server, using this feature. Is it possible that this feature does not work on a Windows-10 version? If not, is there some patch available in order to make this work?

Comment: Make sure Clipboard History is turned ON.  Do a simple copy (notepad) and then WinKey+V . Is the clipboard history enabled?

Comment: @John: thanks for your quick reply, but this does not solve the issue. I have turned on the clipboard history, but still I am not able to copy the mentioned file details (nothing is added to the clipboard history while pressing "Ctrl+C" after selecting a line in the file details.

Comment: What you are trying to do may be dependent on ShortSha.   Have you tried their support services?

Comment: @John: ShortSha is a part of the information in "Product Name", as you can see in the first screenshot. I would be able to copy that information into clipboard.

Comment: If you don't mind using PowerShell/command-line, you can get the file details easily [Get file version in PowerShell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686/get-file-version-in-powershell)

Comment: @w32sh: thanks for your PowerShell advise. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried taking a look in [SysInternals'](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) Process Explorer x64 (as admin)?

Comment: Server 2016 Standard you cannot copy from file Properties, Details tab

Comment: @Arctiic: how could Process Explorer help in this case?

Comment: @gregg: indeed. This morning I checked with a Windows Servers 2016 and I was indeed not able to do so. Which Windows (Server) version allows this?

Comment: I was referring to the `Strings` tab under process properties, which can enumerate it's namesake on running threads.  I'm not certain whether it will extract the data you need, but if it *does* it can be exported to .txt and you can run your own automation to selectively export only what you require (e.g., by hotkey via [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/), or by click via [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/), etc.).

Comment: @Arctiic: I understand your comment now, but it won't fit my needs: I have the situation where I have delivered a DLL to a customer, and I have added the GIT commit hash in the details tab of the DLL. The customer wants me to make an update and in order to be 100% of the source code, corresponding with this DLL, I would like to take the commit hash in the details tab of the DLL and use that for finding the correct source code version. This means that I don't want to start the process, linking that DLL, for doing that.

Comment: [Copy Detailed File Info to Clipboard via Right-Click Menu](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/copy-file-details-version-product-context-menu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PowerShell was almost correct, just missing one pair of parenthesis:

```
Set-Clipboard -Value (Get-Item "C:\Directory\Application.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

To use it in the context-menu, create a `.ps1` script file with the
following contents. Mine was stored in `C:\Temp\test.ps1`.

```
$param1=$args[0]
Set-Clipboard -Value (Get-Item "$param1").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

Now copy the following text into a `.reg` file and then double-click it to
import into the registry. It will create a context-menu action
called "Get DLL version" and uses the above script (be sure to set
the correct path to the script in the text below, with double
back-slashes inside the file-name):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dllfile]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dllfile\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dllfile\shell\DLLVersion]
@="Get DLL version"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dllfile\shell\DLLVersion\command]
@="powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"C:\\Temp\\test.ps1\" \"%1\""
```

The new context-menu entry can be used immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I can't offer much, since your command is almost correct, you only missed by one left bracket, but I can tell you how to do batch processing.

```
(Get-Item "C:\Directory\Application.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

The above gets the information you want, `Set-Clipboard` accepts pipelined arguments, so you can pipeline the output to the cmdlet:

```
(Get-Item "C:\Directory\Application.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion | Set-Clipboard
```

You can also use aliases to make the command shorter:

```
(gi "Path\to\file.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion | Set-Clipboard
```

`gi` is an alias of `Get-Item`.

By default, `Set-Clipboard` clears current clipboard, if you want to retain current clipboard, use `-Append` switch.

I assume you want to get the versions of multiple dlls, you can use `Get-ChildItem` to list all dlls inside in directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "path\to\folder" -File -Force -Recurse -Filter *.dll
```

Aliased:

```
gci "path\to\folder" -file -fo -r -filt *.dll
```

To get the versions of each dll:

```
Get-ChildItem "path\to\folder" -file -force -recurse -filter *.dll | ForEach-Object {$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion}
```

Alias of `ForEach-Object` is `%`
Get the name and version in a string:

```
Get-ChildItem "path\to\folder" -file -force -recurse -filter *.dll | ForEach-Object {"Path: $($_.FullName), Version: $($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion)"}
```

The above creates an array of strings like this:

```
Path: C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll, Version: 14.28.29304.1
```

To join this array into a giant string delimited by newlines:

```
(Get-ChildItem "path\to\folder" -file -force -recurse -filter *.dll | ForEach-Object {"Path: $($_.FullName), Version: $($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion)"}) -Join "`r`n"
```

Finally, paste this whole thing into clipboard:

```
((Get-ChildItem "path\to\folder" -file -force -recurse -filter *.dll | ForEach-Object {"Path: $($_.FullName), Version: $($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion)"}) -Join "`r`n") | Set-Clipboard
```

Wrap all these into a function:

```
Function Clip-DLLVersion {
    param(
    [string]$path,
    [bool]$append = $false
    )
    $data = (Get-ChildItem $path -file -force -recurse -filter *.dll | ForEach-Object {"Path: $($_.FullName), Version: $($_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion)"}) -Join "`r`n"
    Switch ($append)
    {
        $true {Set-Clipboard -Value $data -Append}
        $false {Set-Clipboard -Value $data}
    } 
}
```

Example usage:

```
Clip-DLLVersion -path "$Env:WINDIR\System32"
```

---

### ***Edit***

Updated per comment, `clip` is not an alias of `Set-Clipboard`, so I corrected the aliased command to make it generally applicable.

---

### ***Edit 1***

Fixed several typos in code. I wrote all of it on a phone so I did not had the chance to run it, there was a typo in the first command to get the names, and I copy-pasted that command into subsequent commands, I did not notice it until now.

Comment: Nice post. BTW, `clip` is not an alias of `set-clipboard`. You're piping the output to `clip.exe` actually.

Comment: Such bad luck...

Answer (score 1):

You can try screenshorting using he print screen button on your keyboard. Or simply use any third party software such as Share X. Then use OCR to convert to text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You might be on to something: There are some message boxes which seem to be copied into clipboard in a double way: if I paste them into MS-Paint, I see the screenshot of the message box. If I paste them into a text editor (Notepad or Notepad++) I see the plain text of the message box. For file details this is not (yet) the case. Maybe this technology might help solve my issue.

Comment: I know OCR tech has vastly improved in accuracy over the past few years, but for me I would be uncomfortable with the lack of accountability/validation mechanism for accuracy regardless.  Not sure how important that is for OP though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this via PowerShell and Context Menu for files, do the following:

Open `regedit` and navigate to the following key:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` if you are administrator
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell` if you are a normal user

add a new key under `shell` and Name it as you want your context-menu entry to look like (e.g `CopyProductVersion`)

add a new key called `command` under the key that you just created

edit the `(Default)` property in `command` and enter this and click ok:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -command "(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%V').VersionInfo.ProductVersion | Set-Clipboard"
```

Now you should have a new context menu entry that copies the ProductVersion into your clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file details using PowerShell; it works on Windows 10 as well:

For example, to get the file info for `Autoruns64.exe`, run:

```
(Get-Item "D:\tools\Autoruns64.exe").VersionInfo | format-list * | Clip
```

Regarding the context menu addition, user [SimonS](https://superuser.com/a/1725137/542839) seems to have addressed that part.