# How to copy (in clipboard) detailed information of a file without Powershell?

Tags: windows, filesystems, properties

I would like to come back on [a previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1724553): "How to copy (in clipboard) detailed information of a file?".

That question has been answered using Powershell, and the solution is working fine, but I can't help remembering that I have done such a thing without Powershell.

Just to give you an idea: I have taken the file details of a random file on my computer, and I have selected the size and copied the information to clipboard:

At first:

[image]

Selecting (and copying) size related information:

[image]

After pasting in a general text editor, I see the following:

```
17.3 KB (17,734 bytes)
```

I would like to do the same with some file details (this time with a DLL file):

[image]

... but copying and trying to paste in a text editor does nothing.

As you can see, the information on the "General" tab ("Location", "Size", "Size on disk", ...) is shown in a different way than the information in the "Details" tab ("File description", "Type", ..., "Product version", ...).

Is there a way to get the information in the "Details" tab to look like the information in the "General" tab, and this for Windows-10 computers?

(I'm 100% sure I've done that, but I have no idea on which Windows version or how this was done.)

**Edit: a more general question**
The properties of a file are based on its extension, e.g. for a general file there are the tabs "General", "Security", "Details" and "Previous Versions", for DLL files the tab "Digital Signatures" is added.

Where are these things defined? (I don't find this anywhere in the registry)

**Edit2: how am I so sure this is possible?**
I have worked for a firm where that feature was at the basis of their configuration management, but I have been fired in quite a dirty way, so I prefer not to contact those people again.

Comment: When you asked your question, I did a significant amount of research on multiple versions of Windows, and it has never been possible to copy the information listed in the detail by "copying" the text.  *All that means is that you have always had to use WinAPI functions to copy it.*  I am not aware of any way to do that within the standard Command Prompt, which mean if it's possible outside of PowerShell, then you remember doing it within the command prompt by calling a third-party application.

Comment: @Ramhound: thanks for your quick reply, but I don't really agree: you state that this is basically not possible, but is it possible to reconfigure a Windows platform in such a way that it becomes possible? (E.g. the registry contains "shellex", "PropertySheetHandlers", "Digital Signatures" to deal with the "Digital Signatures" tab. Would anything exist for other tabs?

Comment: You can't call WinAPI functions from the command prompt itself using the limited functions of the scripting language that can be used.